# What are these extra parameters in my ASMX Proxy Methods?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asmx

If I add a web reference from a .NET 1.1 client to a WCF service, the proxy methods generated at the client contain an extra parameter ending with the suffix 'Specified' for each service method parameter, e.g.

```
[OperationContract]
string HelloWorld(string foo, int bar);
```

results in:

```
Service1.HelloWorld(string foo, bool fooSpecified, int bar, bool barSpecified);
```

My service parameters aren't optional so what are these extra parameters at the client, and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: BTW, this is not a "WCF client", but rather is an ASMX client of a WCF service.

Comment: It's a WCF client in the same way you're a bank client without actually being a bank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a difference in the serialization mechanisms used in WCF and ASMX Web Services.
To avoid extra params you must specify XmlSerializerFormat attribute on ServiceContract.

for add read this:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2008/05/17/calling-wcf-services-from-net-1-1.aspx

Comment: Some sense at last. Thank you very much.

Comment: "Page not Found". :'(

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with parameters of a value type when they are permitted to be absent. .NET 1.1 has no way to specify this without the `*specified` parameters. They need to be set to true to indicate that the corresponding parameter is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 1.1 Web services don't have a concept of null so WCF is generating these extra properties for you. fooSpecified = false means foo is really null.

Comment: foo is an _input_ to the service, specified at the client.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need t osay that your parameters *are* required

```
[OperationContract] 
string HelloWorld([RequiredDataParameter] string foo,
                  [RequiredDataParameter] int bar);
```

Comment: Google only has two results for RequiredDataParameter, and one of them is this page, so probably not.