# WCF SOAP Service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I am working on a WCF SOAP service, and I noticed something weird.

I have the following code in my service contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
   [OperationContract]
   int MethodA(int a, int b);

   [OperationContract]
   string MethodB(int a, int b);
}
```

I am not going to give the implemented service class because the implemented MethodA and MethodB are trivial and could do anything.

When I chose to "Add Web Reference" and create a proxy reference in an ASP.NET application that I am using to consume the services, I noticed that the two methods have different arguments on their signature.

For example:

MethodA has the following signature options

```
MethodA(int a,bool aSpecified,int b,bool bSpecified)
```

and MethodB only has the following signature

```
MethodB(int a,bool aSpecified,int b,bool bSpecified,out int MethodBResult,bool methodBResultSpecified)
```

Why would they have different options for signatures?

I need MethodB signature to be the same as MethodA.

what would I need to provide for the last two parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're consuming a WCF service, you should use the "Add Service Reference" (instead of "Add Web Reference" to create a proxy to the service. Those *specified parameters are added for the "old-style" proxies because you could prevent the parameters from being sent to the service (see some answers at the post [What are these extra parameters in my ASMX Proxy Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284760) for more information)